# How to find execution time of multiple subprocesses?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, time, subprocess

I have a list of Linux commands and I'm running each command using subprocess module, I need to figure out how can I find the execution time of each of the commands and return the execution time in a list or dict, in case of dict the Key can be the command name and value be the time in seconds.

i.e. **The moment `(Popen object).poll() == 0` finishes should determine the finish time.**

I'm using **Python 3.5.2**

For Example:

```
import time
import shlex
from subprocess import *`

#list of commands
commands = ['sleep 5', 'ls -l', 'find /usr','sleep 3','uptime']

#executing each command in the list
for command in commands:
     cmd = shlex.split(command)
     # Need to time this and the moment it is finished executing.
     x = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Should return/print:

```
- Commands   Time(secs)
- sleep 5     5.0004   #whatever the time it takes
- ls -l       0.000    #and so on....
```

Comment: do you need the output of the commands?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I donot, so I dont care If I get the output or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Popen` is the poor man's "run in the background" technique. You have control on the process, but if you want to wait for it to end in a non-polling way, you cannot.

if you don't care about the output, just the execution time, you could wrap each `subprocess.call` (`Popen` is no longer needed) in a thread, and update a dictionary command => time spent

Launching the thread does not block, but `call` blocks, letting you time the execution more easily.

```
import threading,time,subprocess,shlex

time_dict = {}

def time_me(command):
    start_time = time.time()
    cmd = shlex.split(command)
    subprocess.call(cmd)
    time_dict[command] = time.time() - start_time

threads = []
commands = ['sleep 5', 'ls -l', 'find /usr','sleep 3','uptime']

for command in commands:
    t = threading.Thread(target=time_me,args=(command,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(time_dict)
```

Comment: this works really efficient! However could you suggest a solution using Popen. Lord Yumma's solution works but only for smaller commands, can we wait for it until it poll() 's

Comment: using Popen & poll avoids the threading but has to poll in an active loop. I wouldn't advise this.

Answer (score 1):

While threads certainly are a solution to this problem (assuming correct handling of shared data), you can alternatively run a while loop:

```
import time
import shlex
from subprocess import *

#list of commands
commands = ['sleep 5', 'ls -l', 'sleep 3', 'uptime', 'find /usr']
times = {}
running = {}
#executing each command in the list
for command in commands:
    start_time = time.time()
    cmd = shlex.split(command)
    times[command] = time.time()
    running[command] = Popen(cmd,
                             # no shell=True, shlex already did the split
                             stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

while len(running):
    finished = set()
    for cmd, proc in running.items():
        if proc.poll() is not None:
            times[cmd] = time.time() - times[cmd]
            finished.add(cmd)
        else:
            proc.communicate() # drain the pipe

    for cmd in finished:
        del running[cmd]

print(times)
```

Note that this will not block (as opposed to its threaded alternative), so it may end up eating your CPU. To lessen the load, you may add a call to `time.sleep` at the end of the loop, making results slightly inaccurate.

Edit:
Since you've used pipes in the example, I assume you want to use the output of (some of) the commands for some meaningful processing. Whether you want to or not, if you don't do `proc.communicate`, you will end up filling your pipe, thus blocking the process. Alternatively, you can of course redirect the output (to some file or /dev/null). Communicating with a process may also alter the results, as does processing :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However after adding extra commands such as 'find /' and 'find /usr', more than 15 mins have passed by but still waiting for it to execute.

Comment: Still no response, plus now its using upto 40% of the CPU, although I'm using a PC 64-bit Core i5, 2.3 ghz (4 CPUs)

Comment: I'm not sure how the busy loop affects 'find', but I've explicitly mentioned the CPU problem. Try `time.sleep(0.1)` as the last statement of the while loop.

Comment: I already tried time.sleep, that does not effect the duration, it's something else, I timed the 'find' command in an another function and it was not taking more than 10 secs.

Comment: Ah, it appears your pipe is filling up. I've updated my response to take that into account.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you for pointing that! But like you said it does alter the results, sometimes it shows similar times for all processes.